# Multiple typecasting in a single line in Java program

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

While messing around with Java syntax today, I tried to compile the following piece of java code:

```
class Mess {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float i = (char)(int)(long)(byte) 100;
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

The code actually gave no compilation or runtime errors. Changing data type of `i` to any other data type like `int` or `double` or `char` also worked. Not only this, introducing operations in the declaration also worked without any errors:

```
float i = (char)+(int)-(long)(byte) 100;
```

When I used auto-format in Netbeans to format the code, the above declaration was formatted as follows:

```
float i = (char) +(int) -(long) (byte) 100;
```

Please help me in understanding how this code is compiled?

Comment: Plus and minus are unary operators in this context Also, why do you feel that the multiple casting should not be allowed?

Comment: Why would I want to cast the same value (or variable) multiple times? I cannot think of a situation where this would be necessary.

Comment: @Bhoot, id you have two integers and want to perform a division you might want to do `int result = (int) ((double) i / j * 100);` for instance.

Comment: @aioobe: This is a good wake up call for me. While I am comfortable using all data structures and other 'complicated' java utils, these fundamentals are so unclear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's basically just a chain of casts and unary `+` and `-`.

```
float i = (char) +(int) -(long) (byte) 100;
```

It's equivalent to

```
byte tmp1 = (byte) 100;
long tmp2 = (long) tmp1;
long tmp3 = -tmp2;
int  tmp4 = (int) tmp3;
int  tmp5 = +tmp4;
char tmp6 = tmp5;
float i = tmp6;
```

The final assignment is from `char` to `float`, which is a widening primitive conversion. See [JLS Chapter 5: Conversions and Promotions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)

> 19 specific conversions on primitive types are called the widening primitive conversions:
>
> - byte to short, int, long, float, or double
> - short to int, long, float, or double
> - **char** to int, long, **float**, or double
> - int to long, float, or double
> - long to float or double
> - float to double

Comment: It isn't quite a corect example, because of '-' sign involved.

Answer (score 0):

Consider it like this:

```
   float i = ((char) +((int) -((long) ((byte) 100))));
```

And each step casts result to it's own type. So, surprisingly 100 became 65436.0
 because of all these intermediate type casts.

Comment: This is due to the cast from `-100` to `char`. The range for `char` is `0`-`65536`.